# dash- OSError: Address 'http://127.0.0.1:8050' already in use

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am using dash with plotly in jupyter notebook. I constantly get this error even I close 8050 port or close all the ports. I think if I run it inside jupyter notebook, I don't need to specify port number, am I correct?   I can fix it by adding port=8060 etc. But because I am running multiple app.run_server() inside same notbook, I have to change port number for each of run_server().
Thanks for your help.

```
app = JupyterDash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([...])
app.run_server(mode='inline')
```

Comment: Means exactly what it says. The tools you can use to check which process is bound to the port vary by operating system; which are you using?

Comment: Wait, you say you're trying to run multiple servers on the same port from inside the same notebook? How do you expect that to work?

Comment: I am using windows 10. Thanks Charles.

Comment: I want to say one of the SysInternals tools can list open ports, but I don't do Windows so that's just a vague memory.

Comment: Hi Charles, I have multiple app.run_server(mode='inline') in same notbook. do I have specify port number for different app.run_server()? I think the system will pick whatever one not used? am I correct?

Answer (score -1):

My current and not ideal solution is to restart my computer. Is not ideal, but it works everytime!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34743373)